# Filezilla: Can I use a OpenSSH format key?

Tags: openssh, filezilla, ubuntu-16.04

Hi I am using Filezilla version 3.17.0 and I'm trying to add a key to a connection in the openssh format. I am quite sure I got this working under Windows, but now I'm under Ubuntu and when I want to select the key under .ssh they don't show up. I don't want a method how to convert the keys to the ppk format, I know how this works. Just is it possible to use the openssh format in Filezilla or have I been mistaken under Windows?

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: *"they don't show up"* - What does that mean? Where do they not show up?

Comment: I added a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, It seems as this is a GUI bug. The key didn't show up. But I tried to just drag and drop the key from nautilus into the select key window and that worked. I was then able to select the key. It also works if you just input the path of the key, even though you can't select them with the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me without any problems for years. If you refer to the directory `.ssh`, that it does not show up in the file browser, then you need to show hidden files (right click -> Show hidden files).

Yes. OpenSSH format is supported by FileZilla.

Comment: I have hidden files enabled.

Comment: Is it really the same path? Do you run filezilla under the same user as your Nautilus?

Comment: It's the same path, and the same user started both nautilus and filezilla. I looked it up with ps aux | grep filezilla and ps aux | grep nautilus.